# How to read a specific column in Unix

Tags: awk, ksh

```
Filesystem    State   1024-blocks      Used       Avail   Capacity  Mounted on
$ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED    71686344    58788360    12897984   82%    /deleteme
```

Here I want to read the first column, meaning only read up to the text `DELETEME`.

I tried, but when I read the first column I get `ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED`.

The entries of the `Filesystem` and `State` columns are treated as one combined column (containing `ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED`).
How can I resolve this?

This is what I tried:

```
df -k DELETEME | tail -1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "};{print NF}'
```

Comment: Filesystem    State   
$ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED these 2 columns traeted as one column only

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your question to clarify it. It seems to me your question is actually about your awk program. Can you add the information what shell you are using? I would guess bash, but I am not sure from your question. (You can add this information as a tag using the edit function).

Comment: My shell is ksh

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure two column values are combined in the output? I guess it must be separated by tabs, so in that case all you need to do is use **awk '{print $1}'** to print the first column. Default field separators for awk is space and tab. In case if you don't want to rely on the default separator specify it explicitly.